# How do you setup the models in Rails 4 for a one to many two way relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Rails and working on learning how relationships work for a camp registration project. I want the uses to have groups coming to camp and to be able to see the user from the group.
My current models are set-up like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :Groups
end
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :User
end
```

Want to be able to call:
User.Group returns the list of groups, but Group.User returns nil. I need to the Group.User to return the user.

Comment: Sure that codes can run correctly? There should be `has_many :groups` first. And if you use ActiveRecord, confirm that migrate works well and had created a relationship table for User and Group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to call those attributes a bit differently.

First, remember that in Ruby, capitalize names represent classes.  You likely mean that you want to be able to do this in your controller to make something available to the view:

@user = User.find(params[:id])

Now in your view you will be able to use @user.groups to reference what amounts to an array.  Please note that it is "groups" rather than "group" because you defined it as a "has_many"

On the other side of that you should find the following works as well, provided that you are populating the user_id field in your Group model:

@group = Group.find(params[:id])

Which makes available @group.user - Again, lower case but now singular because it's a "belongs_to"